# How to match the second group if only the first group is a match

Tags: python, regex, python-datetime

I am trying to write a regex for a python script that matches the second group if only the first group is a match.

I am trying to grab the dates if the text looks like this:

```
Cancel Date: 08/09/19
Cancellation Date: 08/05/19
```

It should not grab the date if the text is anything else other than what is mentioned above.
e.g Due date: 12/34/12 should not match or grab the dates.

Current regex solution:

```
(Cancel Date:|Cancellation Date:)[\s\n\r\t]*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})
```

I am using regex.search().group(2) to grab the info but seem to keep getting a none type attribute error for where the dates need to be. Any help or an alternative solution is appreciated.
I am capturing the regex in a config file with xml format.

Comment: Welcome. Please include the relevant code in your question, with some example data so we can see what the problem might be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: sure! thanks. i'll do that

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me. Did you properly escape your regex-pattern, or make it a raw-string?

```
import re as regex

strings = [
    "Cancel Date: 08/09/19",
    "Cancellation Date: 08/05/19",
    "Due date: 12/34/12"
]

pattern = "Cancel(lation)? Date:[\s]*(\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2})"

for string in strings:
    match = regex.match(pattern, string)
    if match is None:
        print("No Match")
    else:
        print(match.group(2))
```

Output:

```
08/09/19
08/05/19
No Match
```

Comment: I did the needed escaping. However, this doesn't seem to work either. I am adding some more code if it might be relevant. thank you for your help :)

Comment: No worries. Could you provide a good size chunk of the actual data you are parsing? Is it a list of single strings, like I've got in my example, or is it one big string? That way I can make any necessary changes to the regex-pattern.

Comment: It's just a list of single strings I am grabbing from a web page and looks as you have written it. I am not using xml encoding(&lt; &gt;) because that creates more havoc!

Comment: In that case, could you provide the url to the webpage, or at least show how you're getting your `page_source`?

Comment: <td><b>Cancel Date:</b></td><td>08/09/19</td> that's how it looks if i inspect the element.

Comment: and that's probably the reason it is not matching! now it makes sense

Comment: Haha, yeah that's probably why ;)

Comment: thanks for your help though. I had my code working right after because i knew what was wrong!